# How to pass an array of variable length to the input of the neural network?

Tags: feature-selection, data-transformation, embeddings

I have a bunch of two-dimensional points that I want to feed into my neural network as an input. Those points are positions of the visible obstacles around my agent. The main challenge is that the quantity of the obstacles changes over time. All the tutorials I found use fixed amount of inputs. But should I handle variable sets of data? The order of the points is not important.

I could possibly use a fixed amount of inputs and fill the rest with zeros. But for 20 inputs it seems to me that the latter ones (17-20) will be empty in most cases. Wouldn't that make that part of the network behave worse? Also how can it distinguish an empty input ([0, 0]) from an object located in [0, 0]?

In the amazing [OpenAi's hide and seek paper](https://openai.com/blog/emergent-tool-use/) they used `Entity Embeddings` to solve a similar problem. I feel that this is exactly what I need. But I can't find any examples of how it works. Do you have any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Why not just enumerate the objects in the environment (object 1, object 2, ... object n)? If the object is present, encode it as 1, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Sycorax, objects in my environment get destroyed and the new ones are created all the time. But an idea of encoding presence as boolean is nice, thanks.